# Getting number of rows in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently working on having my code safe from sql injection and am practicing on passing user input safely, however it seems to have caused a few problems.

I want to check if the user already exists in the database prior to inputting it, but am having issues getting the number of rows to do this. The latter insert statement works fine.

```
    $Check = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Actor WHERE SurName = ? AND FirstName = ?");
    $Check->bind_param('ss',$SurName ,$FirstName);

    $Check->execute();

    if($Check->num_rows == 0)
    {

        //-----------------Change String To Date----------//
        $dob = str_replace('/', '-', $dob);
        $DOB= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dob));
        //----------------------Insert SQL----------------//
        $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Actor(SurName, FirstName, Gender, DOB) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $insert->bind_param('ssss',$SurName ,$FirstName, $Gender, $DOB);
        if ($insert->execute())
        {
            $Confirm=$FirstName.' '.$SurName.' has been added to our database<br>';
        }
        else
        {die(mysqli_error($conn));}
        mysqli_close($conn);
        //header( "refresh:5;url=addactor.php" );
    }
    else
    {$CheckErr="Actor Already Exists";}
```

EDIT: I found a solution and the answer is below for anyone else having the same problem. The solution was to get the result, then count it and store it in a variable:

```
    $Check = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Actor WHERE SurName = ? AND FirstName = ?");
    $Check->bind_param('ss',$SurName ,$FirstName);
    $Check->execute();
    $result = $Check->get_result();
    $count = $result->num_rows;
    if($count==0)
    {
        //-----------------Change String To Date----------//
        $dob = str_replace('/', '-', $dob);
        $DOB= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dob));
        //----------------------Insert SQL----------------//
        $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Actor(SurName, FirstName, Gender, DOB) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $insert->bind_param('ssss',$SurName ,$FirstName, $Gender, $DOB);
        if ($insert->execute())
        {
            $Confirm=$FirstName.' '.$SurName.' has been added to our database<br>';
        }
        else
        {die(mysqli_error($conn));}
        mysqli_close($conn);
        header( "refresh:5;url=addactor.php" );
    }
    else
    {$CheckErr="Actor Already Exists";}
```

Comment: SELECT count(*) as count FROM Actor WHERE SurName = ? AND FirstName = ?   and then   if($Check->count == 0){

Comment: Thanks for the help, however this didn't work for me. I will edit my question to show my solution for anyone else with this problem.